# My right + left arrow keybinds aren't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, event-listener

I'm trying to make an HTML, CSS, and JavaScript game. When the right and left arrow keys are pressed, the player should move to the right and left. I don't know why, but this code isn't adding an event listener. Any help? Here's the code in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            JavaScript Platformer
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="game" class="game" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</html>
```

This is the code in my script.js file:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var playerImg = new Image();
var player = {
    x: 225,
    y: 375,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
}

function draw() {
    playerImg.onload = function () {
        
        // draws the player image
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    }
    
    playerImg.src = "images/player.png";
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (event.keycode == 37) {
        
        // deletes the last image so the image doesn't get duplicated
        ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height);
        
        // moves the player
        player.x -= 20;
    }
    if (event.keycode == 39) {
        
        // deletes the last image so the image doesn't get duplicated
        ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height);
        
        // moves the player
        player.x -= 20;
    }
}, false);

setInterval(draw, 100);
```

This is the code in my CSS file:

```
.game {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Any help? I don't see any problems with this code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see if the event is firing, and if it is what keycode it thinks has been pressed?

Comment: Please use keyCode instead of keycode. There must be a typo. I confirmed that it worked correctly after correcting your typo.

Comment: And please update your code to ```player.x += 20;``` in Right Arrow key event(keyCode: 39)

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is a depreciated property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Obsolete_properties and you should not use it. Use `KeyboardEvent.code` or `KeyboardEvent.key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a small typo in your code. It's `event.keyCode == 39` and not `event.keycode == 39` (notice the C is uppercase in keyCode)

The same goes for `event.keycode == 39`. It should be `event.keyCode == 39`

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use `keyCode`

The [answer by sagar1025](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107414/3877726) has the reason for the bug however [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Obsolete_properties) and should be avoided.

Rather use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

### IO state rather than IO events

Also linking player movement directly to IO events,like the keyboard, will result in behavior that is different for different OS / Devices / setups. Eg key repeat rates can vary a lot.

It also makes it very hard to react to key combinations as key events are per key. You can not know if a key down is going to be followed by the combo key down. eg `down and left` for diagonal.

Use the keyboard events to track the state of the keyboard (only of what you need to know).

In the game loop read the keyboard state to perform actions.

This means that the behavior of your game is consistent across devices.

For example

```
const keys = {  // name of key code you want to track state of
    ArrowLeft: false,
    ArrowRight: false,
};
function keyEventListener(event) {
    if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {
        keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyEventListener);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyEventListener);
```

Then in the game animation loop just check the state of the keys

```
// only when one move key is down
if ((keys.ArrowLeft || keys.ArrowRight) && keys.ArrowRight !== keys.ArrowLeft) { player.x -= 5 }
    if (keys.ArrowLeft) { player.x -= 5 }
    if (keys.ArrowRight) { player.x += 5 }
}
```

Note that if the player holds down left and right the player will not move

### Demo

Example using `keyup` and `keydown` event listeners to track keyboard state, and using the key state to control game behavior.

```js
// hold keyboard state
const keys = {  // name of key codes you want to track state of
    ArrowLeft: false,
    ArrowRight: false,
    ArrowUp: false,
    ArrowDown: false,
};
function keyEventListener(event) { // simple state tracker
    if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {
        keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyEventListener);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyEventListener);


const player = {x: canvas.width / 2, y: canvas.height / 2, moving: false};
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (keys.ArrowLeft) { player.x -= 1; player.moving = true }
    if (keys.ArrowRight) { player.x += 1; player.moving = true }
    if (keys.ArrowUp) { player.y -= 1; player.moving = true }
    if (keys.ArrowDown) { player.y += 1; player.moving = true }
    drawPlayer(player);    
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

    
function drawPlayer(player) {
    if (player.moving) {
        player.moving = false;
        player.x = player.x < 0 ? 0 : player.x;
        player.x = player.x > canvas.width - 10 ? canvas.width - 10 : player.x;
        player.y = player.y < 8 ? 8 : player.y;
        player.y = player.y > canvas.height - 16 ? canvas.height - 16 : player.y;
        const footB = (player.x + player.y / 2) % 20;
        const footA = (player.x + player.y / 2+ 10) % 20;
        const head = ((player.x + player.y / 2)/2) % 8;

        ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
        if (footB > 10) { ctx.fillRect(player.x + 8 - (footB-10), player.y + 10, 4, 6) }
        else { ctx.fillRect(player.x - 2 + footB, player.y + 8, 4, 6) }
        ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 10, 10);
         ctx.fillRect(player.x + 2 + (head < 4 ? head : (4 - head)), player.y -8, 6, 6);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#AAA";
        if (footA > 10) { ctx.fillRect(player.x + 8 - (footA - 10), player.y + 10, 4, 6) }
        else { ctx.fillRect(player.x - 2 + footA, player.y + 8, 4, 6) }
    } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
        ctx.fillRect(player.x - 2, player.y + 10, 4, 6);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 10, 10);
        ctx.fillRect(player.x + 2, player.y -8, 6, 6);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#AAA";
        ctx.fillRect(player.x + 8, player.y + 10, 4, 6);
    }
}

addEventListener("click", () => {
    start.textContent = "Arrow keys to move"
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}, {once: true})
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="start">Click to focus</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```